# Word document - hide radio button control on File Save/Print

Tags: events, vba, module, ms-word

I am able to create module event handler for save/print but unable to access controls on document to change say ..I have radio button on Document i want to hide it on File-> Save. Any help would be appreciuated suffering from 2 days.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in the ThisDocument object in Word VBA. It should allow you to run whatever code you need prior to saving the document.

```
Public WithEvents appWord As Word.Application

Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforeSave _
 (ByVal Doc As Document, _
 SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
 Cancel As Boolean)

'Put your code here

End Sub
Private Sub Document_Open()
Set appWord = Application
End Sub
```

Note that this will not work until appWord has been initialized, which is why I placed it in the Document_Open event code(there are likely better ways). In other words, this code will not run until you re-open the document.

Comment: this far in creating eventhandler i was there. Now how can i say in Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforeSave _ 
 (ByVal Doc As Document, _ 
 SaveAsUI As Boolean, _ 
 Cancel As Boolean) 
 
'Like in view code something lik below which is not allowed now
 me.Label1.width=10
End Sub 
anybody any light

Comment: can you pls show how i ll code ter u specified to hide control on document